# Expected value of a random variable $X$, with $X$ being the number of days where at least one person celebrates his birthday

Tags: probability, expectation

> Take a look at a randomly chosen group of $n \in \Bbb N$ people. Let $X$ be the number of days (out of $365$ days), where at least one person celebrates his  birthday. Think of $X$ as a random variable and let $n = 50$.

My attempt:

I don't think it's possible to give a definite answer here since we don't know how many people there are who celebrate their birthday on the same day. I would argue like this:

First, let us define

$X := \sum_{k=1}^{365} X_k \{0, 1\}$

with

$X_k := 1$, when a person celebrates his birthday and $0$ otherwise.

This means that $X_k \{0, 1\} \le 50$ since $n = 50$.

The probability for one person celebrating his birthday on day $j \in \{1, ..., 365\}$ is $1 \over 365$, hence, we get

$E(X)$ = $\sum_{k=1}^{365} X_k \{0, 1\}$ $*$ $50 \over 365$ $\le$ $2500 \over 365$ $= 6,85$.

Additionally, I would like to understand what this specific value is actually giving me here.

**Edit:**

After a discussion in the comments, I came to the conclusion that it would be better to calculate $\sum_{k=1}^{365} X_k \{0, 1\} \left(364 \over 365\right)^n$. Do I still have to write this as an inequality?

Comment: Good method, bad algebra.  If you have $n$ people, the probability that at least one has a specified birthday is not $\frac n{365}$  Suppose $n>365$...that formula would give a value greater than $1$.  To do it correctly, compute the probability that all $n$ people have a different birthday.

Comment: To clarify:  specify a birthday.  The probability that a random individual has a birthday other than the specified one is, clearly, $\frac {364}{365}$.  By independence, the probability that none of $n$ people have the specified birthday is therefore $\left( \frac {364}{365} \right)^n$.

Comment: Thanks! But why is the probability that one person has a birthday on an arbitrary day is $364 \over 365$, but the probability that $n$ persons **don't** is $(364 \over 365)$$^n$?

Comment: Not following.  Let's say we pick Jan-1 as the specified date.  The probability that a randomly selected person was born on Jan-1 is, clearly, $\frac 1{365}$ hence the probability that this person was born on some other day is $\frac {364}{365}$.  If you have two people, the odds that neither of them was born on Jan-1 is $\frac {364}{365} \times \frac {364}{365}$, and so on.

Comment: So I actually have to calculate $\sum_{k=1}^{365} X_k \{0, 1\} $ $\left(364 \over 365\right)^n$?

Comment: Well.  $\left( \frac {364}{365} \right)^n$ is the probability that nobody in your sample was born on the specified day.  Therefore, the probability that at least one person was born on the specified day is $1- \left( \frac {364}{365} \right)^n$.

Comment: Okay, so I receive the expected value $6,41$, but assuming that everyone of these $50$ persons have their birthday on a different day. So I'd still have to write this as an inequality, I think?

Comment: You've lost me.  For $50$ people the answer is clearly not $6.41$.  Why would you assume that all $50$ were born on different days?  And what inequality are you talking about?  The expected number is a number, it isn't given by some inequality.

Comment: But how do I have to handle $X_k\{0, 1\}$ then? It's $1$ when there is a person that has his birthday on a specific day, hence, $X\{0, 1\}$ is at most $50$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really not following you.  $X_i$ is the indicator variable for day $i$, yes?  As such $E[X_i]$ is the probability that at least one person is born on day $i$, so $E[X_i]=1-\left( \frac {364}{365} \right)^n$.  That's the same for all $i$ of course so $E[X]=365\times \left(1-\left( \frac {364}{365} \right)^n\right)$.

Comment: For $n=50$ I get $46.78633607$ which certainly feels like a sensible answer.

Comment: From my interpretation, $X_k$ is not the indicator variable for day $k$, but the variable that tells me whether there is someone who has his birthday on day $k$ or not. That's what they gave us as a hint and that's what I constructed with it.

Comment: That's what an indicator variable is.

Comment: Should point out:  your question is very poorly phrased, so possibly I am answering the wrong thing (I am answering the question in the heading).  Nowhere in the question do you suppose that $n=50$, yet at some point you just declare that.  $E[X]$ isn't a random variable, it's a number.  Your sum should be $E[X]=\sum E[X_i]$.

Comment: But then my suggestion above doesn't make sense from the very beginning since there could be at most $50$ summands.

Comment: I truly have no idea what you are talking about.  Sorry. I suggest you edit your question to state clearly what you are assuming and what you are asking.  If $n=50$, then say so.  Don't just introduce it later on.

Comment: Did it. I'm talking about my own sum there. $X_k\{0, 1\}$ is defined the way I did above. So $X \le 50$.

Comment: Ok, and with that question my method and my computation should be correct.  I get $E[X]=46.78633607$  which is just a little less than $50$. That means that, out of $50$ people we expect some redundancies in the birthdays, but not many.  Seems right to me.

Comment: But this doesn't fit to my own approach above with the $X_k\{0, 1\}$. Is this wrong then?

Comment: I used your approach exactly!  The only thing I changed was that I repaired your faulty computation of the expected value of $X_i$.

Comment: So $X_k\{0,1\} = 365$? At least that's the way I interpret your calculation.  Sorry for my missunderstanding here.

Comment: I give up, sorry.  This is my last comment, but for the benefit of the next reader I suggest you define $X_k\{0,1\}$ more clearly than you have.  Actually, you don't define it at all.  You define $X_k$ to be the indicator variable telling us whether or not somebody in the sample was born on day $k$.  You never define $X_k\{0,1\}$.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion here, so I will write up my calculation in greater detail.  It is possible that I am answering the wrong question so, to be clear, I am answering this question:

Question:  Let $X$ be the random variable defined to be the number of distinct birthdays in  sample of $n$ randomly chosen individuals (assuming, as usual, that only $365$ birthdays are possible and that each is equally probable).  Compute $E[X]$, the expected value of $X$.  What is this value when $n=50$?

To do it, we introduce the indicator variables $Y_i$ for each date $i$.  Thus $Y_i=1$ if $i$ is a birthday for at least one person in the sample, and $Y_i=0$ otherwise.  (Note:  I believe that$Y_i=X_i$ in the OP's notation, but I am not sure).

We remark that $$X=\sum_{i=1}^{365}Y_i\implies E[X]=\sum_{i=1}^{365}E[Y_i]$$

Here, of course, we have used the [Linearity of Expectation](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Linearity_of_Expectation_Function).

We need to compute $E[Y_i]$.  Of course this is just $p_i$ where $p_i$ denotes the probability that at least one person in the sample was born on day $i$.  Since the probability that an individual was born on a day different than $i$ is $\frac {364}{365}$, we see that $$p_i=1-\left( \frac {364}{365} \right)^n$$

We deduce that $$E[X]=365\times \left(1-\left( \frac {364}{365} \right)^n\right)$$

Sanity check:  For $n=1$ this is $1$, as it should be.  For $n=2$ we get $1.997260274$ which makes sense (it should be slightly less than $2$ as there is a small chance that your two random people share a birthday). Indeed, with $n=2$ a simple computation shows that $X=1$ with probability $\frac 1{365}$ and $X=2$ with probability $\frac {364}{365}$ so, in this case, $E[X]=1\times \frac 1{365}+2 \times \frac {364}{365}=\frac {729}{365}=1.997260\dots$ as predicted. And, as $n\to \infty$ this expression approaches $365$, as of course it ought to.

For $n=50$ we get $46.78633607$ which seems sensible enough.  It is less than $50$ as it must be, but it is still fairly close to $50$ reflecting the plausible fact that we expect a small number of redundancies.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I still don't understand your definition of $X$. If $X$ can be denoted this way, this means that $Y_i = 1$ for every $i = \{1, ..., 365\}$. This means that on an arbitrary day $i$, there is at least one person who has his birthday. But since $n = 50$, I don't see why this should be the case.

Comment: That is nonsense.  $X$ is the random variable which denotes the number of  distinct birthdays in your sample.  If, say, $n=1$, then $X=1$.  If $n=2$, then $X=1$ or $2$, with $2$ a lot more likely than $1$.  At no point did I say that $X=365$.  That is simply something you made up.